# jQuery .load keeps reloading in Rails App

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using jQuery `.load` to load in a view via Ajax. For some reason it keeps making a request to the server.

```
$("#service_level").load("/charts/service_level", function() {
  return false;
});
```

and this is the view it's loading

```
<%= content_tag :div, "", id: "shipments-by-service-type", data: {shipments: @charts[:service_analysis][:spend_data]} %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var dataArr, obj, prop;

  dataArr = [];
  obj = $("#shipments-by-service-type").data("shipments");
  for (prop in obj) {
    dataArr.push({
      label: prop,
      value: obj[prop]
    });
  }

  Morris.Donut({
    element: "shipments-by-service-type",
    data: dataArr,
    preUnits: '$'
  });

</script>
```